# Can this cylindrical shell integral problem be done with washers instead?

Tags: definite-integrals

Instead of using shells, can I do this problem via horizontal integration and subtracting the smaller circle from the larger circle and use washers instead?

[image]

Is the volume just:

$\int$ Area of larger circle - Area of smaller circle \, dy ?

outer circle equation: $x = \sqrt{y} $
inner circle equation: $x = y$
$$\int_0^1 \pi (outer radius)^2 - \pi (inner radius)^2 \, dy$$

$$\int_0^1 \pi y - \pi y^2\, dy$$

$$ \left [ \pi \frac{y^2}{2} - \pi \frac{y^3}{3} \right ]_0^1$$

$$\left [ \pi \frac{1}{2} - \pi \frac{1}{3} \right ]$$

$$\frac{3\pi}{6} - \frac{2 \pi}{15} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

This right?

Comment: There is just a small typo here $$\int_0^1 \pi y - \pi y^2\,\color{red}{dy}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a correct application of the [disk method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx).

Maybe it is just a typo, but note that we are integrating with repect to $y$ then the integral is

$$\int_0^1 \pi y - \pi y^2\,\color{red}{dy}$$